# Retrieving channel list with Jerklib

Tags: java, irc

As a school project we are writing an IRC client in Java. In order to keep off the low level coding stuff, we are allowed to use jerklib to handle the connection. Unfortunately, the library is not well documented (my opinion at least) and there is one thing in particular which I struggle with:

I want to retrieve a list of available channels from the server I am connecting too. There is a method called `chanList()` which supposedly does exactly that. Quote from documentation:

> Get a List of Channels from server.

However, this method is of type `void`, i.e it does not return anything. Is there any way around this, or another way to retrieve this list?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a method `public void receiveEvent(IRCEvent e)` as described in [Getting started](http://jerklib.wikia.com/wiki/Getting_started). This should get you started:

```
public void receiveEvent(IRCEvent e) {
  if (e.getType() == Type.CHANNEL_LIST_EVENT) {
    ...
  }
}
```